# Gluing two diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M_1,M_2$ be two $n$-dimensional closed manifolds and suppose that $M_i=\bar{U}_i^+\cup \bar{U}_i^-$ where $\bar{U}_i^\pm$ are compact codimension zero sub-manifolds with boundary so that $\bar{U}_i^+\cap \bar{U}_i^-=\Sigma_i$ are smooth codimension one submanifolds in $M_i$.

If there are diffeomorphisms $\phi^\pm :\bar{U}_1^\pm \to \bar{U}_2^\pm$ so that $\phi^+|_{\Sigma_1}=\phi^-|_{\Sigma_1}$, then it is clear that there is a homeomorphism $\phi: M_1\to M_2$ which restricts to the $\phi^\pm$.

Can this homeomorphism be smoothed to give a diffeomorphism $\hat{\phi}:M_1\to M_2$?

Comment: Note that the setup here is a local problem. It reduces to: given a homeomorphism of $\Sigma \times [-1,1]$ which is a diffeomorphism away from $\Sigma \times 0$, that preserves $\Sigma \times 0$, and is "1-sided smooth", can it be modified in an arbitrarily small nbhd if $\Sigma \times 0$ to make it a diffeomorphism? The answer should be yes, but I can't describe how right now.

Comment: After some searching I found a this theorem stated in "An Introduction to Morse Thoery" by Yukio Matsumoto (its Theorem 2.8).  However, the author does not provide a proof (or reference to one) just a sketch...

Comment: Theorem 4.1 in [Obstructions to the Smoothing of Piecewise-Differentiable Homeomorphisms](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970228) by James Munkres appears to be relevant.